# listeners from dnd-kit are interfering with the input:checkbox's onChange event

Tags: reactjs, input, drag-and-drop, drag, dnd-kit

### listeners from dnd-kit are interfering with the input:checkbox's `onChange` event

When I work with input:checkbox `onchange` event dnd-kit's `{...listeners}` interfere with the onchange event. Listeners disables onchange event in the input **(I checked for input:checkbox and input:radio)** element. If I remove/disable/commnet-out the {...listeners} input:checkbox event works just fine.
But I need both {...listeners} and onchange event as without `{...listeners}` I cannot implement drag and drop.

**The code where I tried is given below:**

```js
<div
            {...attributes}
            {...listeners}
            ref={setNodeRef}
            style={style}
            className={styles.itemWrapper}
        >
            <div
                className={styles.item}>
                <img src={item.image} alt="Image title goes here..." />
                <input type="checkbox" id={item.id.toString()}
                    onChange={() => {
                        console.log('checked/unchecked') // doesn't print in console
                        handleSelection(item.id)
                    }}
                />
                <label htmlFor={item.id.toString()} ></label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

** If I disable `{...listeners}` onchange event works fine **

```js
<div
            {...attributes}
           // {...listeners} // disabled
            ref={setNodeRef}
            style={style}
            className={styles.itemWrapper}
        >
            <div
                className={styles.item}>
                <img src={item.image} alt="Image title goes here..." />
                <input type="checkbox" id={item.id.toString()}
                    onChange={() => {
                        console.log('checked/unchecked') // print in console 
                        handleSelection(item.id)
                    }}
                />
                <label htmlFor={item.id.toString()} ></label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```js
<div
            {...attributes}
            {...listeners}
            ref={setNodeRef}
            style={style}
            className={styles.itemWrapper}
        >
            <div
                className={styles.item}>
                <img src={item.image} alt="Image title goes here..." />
                <input type="checkbox" id={item.id.toString()}
                    onChange={() => {
                        console.log('checked/unchecked') // on change event should work with {...listenters enabled}
                        handleSelection(item.id)
                    }}
                />
                <label htmlFor={item.id.toString()} ></label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try to put delay in useSensors, then it will not drag until user holds the element.

Check in documentation:
[Pointer Activation constraints](https://docs.dndkit.com/api-documentation/sensors/pointer#activation-constraints) or [Touch Activation constraints](https://docs.dndkit.com/api-documentation/sensors/touch#activation-constraints).

```
const sensors = useSensors(
    useSensor(MouseSensor, {
      activationConstraint: {
        distance: 8,
      },
    }),
    useSensor(TouchSensor, {
      activationConstraint: {
        delay: 200,
        tolerance: 6,
      },
    }),
    useSensor(KeyboardSensor, {
      coordinateGetter: sortableKeyboardCoordinates,
    }),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to prevent the mouse event from bubbling up in the input event handler，I have encountered similar problems，hope it work for you too

like this :

```
const handleKeyDown =(e:any) => {
    if(e.key===' '){
        e.stopPropagation()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use a drag handle, instead of the entire element being draggable.  then the listeners won't conflict.

```
<div
    ref={setNodeRef}
    style={style}
    className={styles.itemWrapper}
>
    <div className={styles.item}>
        <div className="dragHandle" {...attributes} {...listeners}>drag handle</div>
        <img src={item.image} alt="Image title goes here..." />
        <input type="checkbox" id={item.id.toString()}
            onChange={() => {
            console.log('checked/unchecked') // on change event should work with {...listenters enabled}
            handleSelection(item.id)
            }}
        />
        <label htmlFor={item.id.toString()} ></label>
    </div>
</div>
```